# Angular move assets folder to Azure Storage

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage

in my Angular application, I want to move all the `assets` to Azure Storage.

*Justification*: I have lots of large files that "pollute" the `assets` folder in my repo. These are static files that don't change.

We are hosted on Azure so the idea is to store the `assets` folder on Azure Storage.

I am not allowed to have a public Azure Storage folder. So access to the folder has to be restricted like:

[image]

I do not have any clue how to tell Angular to use my **protected** storage.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please create  a private endpoint in your Storage account under Networking section.

While creating the endpoint, select the target sub-source as blob. Select your virtual network and subnet

[image]

If you hosted your  application in azure web app, integrate your web app with vnet. You need your app plan above  S1 to integrate your  web app with vnet.

Under networking section of your web app, in the outbound traffic enable vnet integration. Add your vnet and subnet.

[image]

If you hosted your application in a VM, you can integrate your VM with your vnet.

So, your angular application will be able to use your protected storage via the private endpoint.

Reference  :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet